# Using Z3 and SMT-LIB to find highest palindromic product

Tags: math, z3, smt

Based on ["Test-Only Development" with the Z3 Theorem Prover](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2014/07/07/38818/), I'm trying to encode [Project Euler problem 4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) in SMT-LIB and solve it using Z3.

The problem is to find the largest palindromic integer product of two three-digit numbers. The solution is `993 * 913 = 906609`.

In the code below, I've only been able to encode that two three-digit numbers should be palindromic. This produces the correct, but not maximal, value of `604406`.

How can I change my code so that the maximal value of `906609` is found?
I've tried using `(maximize (* p q))`, but that reports an error, saying `Objective function '(* p q)' is not supported`.  I can tweak the range of `a`, but I'm looking for a way to have Z3 do that for me.

What I have so far is:

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const c Int)

(declare-const p Int)
(declare-const q Int)

(declare-const pq Int)

(define-fun satisfy ((pq Int)) Bool
 (and
  (<= 1 a 9)
  (<= 0 b 9)
  (<= 0 c 9)

  (<= 100 p 999)
  (<= p q 999)

  (= pq
     (* p q)
     (+ (* 100001 a)
        (*  10010 b)
        (*   1100 c)))))

(assert (satisfy pq))

; Does not work:
;(maximize (* p q))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Running this with `z3 -smt2 e4.smt2` as-is produces:

```
sat
(model
  (define-fun q () Int
    913)
  (define-fun p () Int
    662)
  (define-fun c () Int
    4)
  (define-fun b () Int
    0)
  (define-fun a () Int
    6)
  (define-fun pq () Int
    604406)
)
```

Comment: Use of `maximize` requires building the optimization branch of Z3. Another possible solution for finding maximal values is to assert there are no smaller solutions. I never got this working for Euler 4 (see comments on my blog), but I used a similar solution for [this somewhat simpler problem](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2015/03/05/38845/).

Comment: Yep, I managed to find the opt branch, and I know too little theoretical CS to have a clue why maximize doesn't work (it seems to complain that multiplication is unsupported; I guess this has to do with the fact that we're high up in the complexity tree).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is

```
    (declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const c Int)

(declare-const p Int)
(declare-const q Int)

(declare-const pq Int)

(define-fun satisfy ((pq Int)) Bool
 (and
  (<= 1 a 9)
  (<= 0 b 9)
  (<= 0 c 9)

  (<= 100 p 999)
  (<= p q 999)

  (= pq
     (* p q)
     (+ (* 100001 a)
        (*  10010 b)
        (*   1100 c)))))

(assert (satisfy pq))
(assert (> pq 888888))


(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

and the corresponding output is

```
sat
(model 
(define-fun pq () Int 906609) 
(define-fun q () Int 993) 
(define-fun p () Int 913) 
(define-fun c () Int 6) 
(define-fun b () Int 0) 
(define-fun a () Int 9) )
```

Please run this code online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/8re1).

Comment: While this works, it's not what I'm looking for. I can tweak any of the variables (p, q, pq, a, etc.) to get the answer I know is there. What I'm looking for is a way to encode the constraint that the produkt pq should be the highest possible, given the other constraints. Imagine I don't know the answer beforehand and want this to be found automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Other possible solution:  We search for a number `efggfe`  which is the product of the numbers `9ab` and `9cd`. Using the code

```
 (declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const c Int)
(declare-const d Int)
(declare-const e Int)
(declare-const f Int)
(declare-const g Int)
(assert (and (>= a 0) (<= a 9)))
(assert (and (>= b 0) (<= b 9)))
(assert (and (>= c 0) (<= c 9)))
(assert (and (>= d 0) (<= d 9)))
(assert (and (>= e 0) (<= e 9)))
(assert (and (>= f 0) (<= f 9)))
(assert (and (>= g 0) (<= g 9)))
(assert (= (* (+ 900 (* 10 a) b)  (+ 900 (* 10 c) d))      
           (+ (* 100000 e) (* 10000 f) (* 1000 g) (* 100 g) (* 10 f) e)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

we obtain the output

```
sat 
(model 
(define-fun g () Int 6) 
(define-fun f () Int 0) 
(define-fun e () Int 9) 
(define-fun d () Int 3) 
(define-fun c () Int 1) 
(define-fun b () Int 3) 
(define-fun a () Int 9) )
```

which corresponds to the number `906609`.

Please run this code online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/mslTf).

To verify that `906609` is the maximum we run the following code

```
 (declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const c Int)
(declare-const d Int)
(declare-const e Int)
(declare-const f Int)
(declare-const g Int)
(assert (and (>= a 0) (<= a 9)))
(assert (and (>= b 0) (<= b 9)))
(assert (and (>= c 0) (<= c 9)))
(assert (and (>= d 0) (<= d 9)))
(assert (and (>= e 0) (<= e 9)))
(assert (and (>= f 0) (<= f 9)))
(assert (and (>= g 0) (<= g 9)))
(assert (= (* (+ 900 (* 10 a) b)  (+ 900 (* 10 c) d))      
           (+ (* 100000 e) (* 10000 f) (* 1000 g) (* 100 g) (* 10 f) e)    ) )
(assert (>  (+ (* 100000 e) (* 10000 f) (* 1000 g) (* 100 g) (* 10 f) e)        906609))           

(check-sat)
```

and the corresponding output is

```
unsat
```

Please run the last code  [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Hb2H)

Comment: Aren't you just hiding a requirement that the number should consist of two factors that each are larger than 900? `(* (+ 900 (* 10 a) b) (+ 900 (* 10 c) d))` ? Yes, this works, but again we're still giving Z3 strong hints that we can only know in hindsight. I was hoping that we could have Z3 say "this is the max" without having to do reruns. Wouldn't it be possible to use `push` and `pop` for things like that? Thanks so much for the good answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for still.